# Converting a string into a jquery element and appending it to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do what the title says with the following (admittedly terribly written) code:

```
$('.right').append($('<li class="btn log-out-button"><a data-method="delete" data-remote="true" format="json" href="' + data.log_out_path + '" class="standout-primary" rel="no-follow>Sign Out</a></li>
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong with it, but all that shows up is the following HTML:

```
<li class="btn log-out-button></li>
```

Why is it ignoring the inner HTML I wrote in my string?

Comment: You have a missing quote.  `rel="no-follow>`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: @WesleyMurch—I expect that's a typo, otherwise the OP wouldn't run at all as it's not a valid expression.

Comment: @RobG Well aside from the fact that the code in the OP is truncated (missing a couple closing parentheses), it will actually run and produce the result reported.

Comment: Runs fine http://jsfiddle.net/x8kry/ with all the typos corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this code

```
$('.right').append($('<li class="btn log-out-button"><a data-method="delete" data-remote="true" format="json" href="' + data.log_out_path + '" class="standout-primary" rel="no-follow>Sign Out</a></li>
```

Missing `barces/quotes`, instead try this clean approach

```
var link = $('<a/>', {
    'data-method':'delete',
    'data-remote':'true',
    'format':'json',
    'href': data.log_out_path, // make sure you have 'data' in current scope
    'class':'standout-primary',
    'rel':'no-follow',
    'text':'Sign Out'
});
var li = $('<li/>', { 'class':'btn log-out-button' }).append(link);
$('.right').append(li);
```

[**An Example Here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/cH4Xz/)